# Nginx reverse proxy with IP in the request

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

am struggling finding a solution with reverse proxy.

The goal is to be able to dynamically reroute, based on URI path, the incoming requests, e.g :

https://a.b.c/23432/IP.IP.IP.IP.IP/Path should be proxied to https://IP.IP.IP.IP:23432/Path

While it is working at first sight with

```
  location  ~ ^/(?<targetport>([0-9]+)?)/(?<targethost>[^/]+) {

    proxy_pass            http://$targethost:$targetport;
[...]
```

in the end, only the first element (index.html) is served correctly. The requests made by this page (let's say js/my.js) obviously forget the return path, and are generated to access https://a.b.c/js/my.js, and fail to be served.

I tried setting http_referer (even reverse_proxying the request to it) but it doesn't help as am unable to reparse it correctly

What am I missing here ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, the proxied site was prefixing all the resources with /, killing the initial path